# TextView doesn't changes color in material when using colorOnBackground

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

```
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/purple_700</item>
```

colorOnBackground has no effect on the color of the TextView.

Comment: Facing same issue here. Any solution for this?